# Is $\mathcal A^{\mathcal A}\sim\mathcal B^{\mathcal B}\implies\mathcal A\sim\mathcal B$ true? (Does A^A ~ B^B imply A ~ B? --- A, B categories)

Tags: category-theory, functors

Let $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ be nonempty categories whose categories $\mathcal A^{\mathcal A}$ and $\mathcal B^{\mathcal B}$ of endofunctors are equivalent.

> Are $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ necessarily equivalent?

Implicit assumption: we are working in ZFC, and we assume that ZFC is consistent.

If my understanding is correct, [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/6594/461) of Joel David Hamkins implies that one cannot prove that the answer is Yes, so that either the answer is No, or the question is undecidable. (I think that the answer is No.)

[Reminder 1: Categories are generalized sets in the following sense. Given a set $S$ let $\mathcal C(S)$ be the category whose objects are the elements of $S$ and whose only morphisms are the identity morphisms. Then the assignment $S\mapsto\mathcal C(S)$ commutes with exponentials in the obvious sense.]

[Reminder 2: Infinite cardinals $\kappa$ satisfy $\kappa^\kappa=2^\kappa$. Indeed $\kappa^\kappa\le(2^\kappa)^\kappa=2^{\kappa\kappa}=2^\kappa\le\kappa^\kappa$.]

Comment: Crossposted on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/333902/461

Comment: I will just point out that it's better not to use title consisting only of a single MathJax formula: [MathJax menu obliterates link menu when the entire link is LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1204). (Of course, I wish I had something to say about the question rather than just about the formatting. Let's hope it gets answered on MO.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak - Thanks! I hope it's ok now.

Comment: Note for future readers, this has a nice answer on MO now.